# I am not able to parse mysql data to the face recognition camera window

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, face-recognition

**In the face Recognition window tab, it recognizes my face but it is unable to get information of Name, ID, Roll No, and Department from MySQL Database.**

Code for drawing coordinates on Face and putting text :

```
    def face_recog(self):
    def draw_boudary(img, classifier, scaleFactor, minNeigbors, color, text, clf):
        if img is not None and img.shape[0] > 0 and img.shape[1] > 0:
            gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            features = classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_image, scaleFactor, minNeigbors)

            coord = []

            for (x, y, w, h) in features:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                id, predict = clf.predict(gray_image[y:y + h, x:x + w])
                confidence = int((100 * (1 - predict / 300)))

                conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="08052002H@ck",
                                               database="face_recognizer")
                my_cursor = conn.cursor()

                my_cursor.execute("select name from student where ID=" + str(id))
                n = "+".join(my_cursor)

                my_cursor.execute("select Dep from student where ID=" + str(id))
                d = "+".join(my_cursor)

                my_cursor.execute("select Roll_No from student where ID=" + str(id))
                r = "+".join(my_cursor)

                my_cursor.execute("select ID from student where ID=" + str(id))
                i = "+".join(my_cursor)

                if confidence > 77:
                    cv2.putText(img, f"ID:{i}", (x, y - 80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 3)
                    cv2.putText(img, f"Roll No:{r}", (x, y - 55), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 3)
                    cv2.putText(img, f"Department:{d}", (x, y - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255),3)
                    cv2.putText(img, f"Name:{n}", (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 3)

                else:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
                    cv2.putText(img, "Unknown Face", (x, y - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 3)

                coord = [x, y, w, h]

            return coord
```

[image: Here is the Sample image of What i am expecting and what i am getting:]

[image: This is the Table Structure and what i am trying to pass as Input]

Comment: The problem is related to MySQL. Please share sample data with table structure. The data you are passing to MySQL query, and the value returned. Also, share expected output from the sample data.

Comment: You should use prepared statements to avoid SQL inhjection. Also, it doesn´t make sense to do 4 queries to get 4 different columns for the same ID. You can get all of them in just 1 query